Can your school ban you from sending e-mails?
My school has banned every student from sending e-mails to each other. I'm not sure if this is a thing that schools are allowed to do or not, but I feel that they shouldn't be able to. Our school is small so having full servers isn't the issue, I think that this shouldn't be allowed.
PS - Would I be able to file a lawsuit against the school?

Has the school issued a complete ban on email communication between students, or is it somehow limited in time (not during school hours) or resources (not using school equipment/addresses)?

Or limited to the use of a school-specific email system? And can it be categorized as “the government” or is it a private institution?

There are a lot of different circumstances that could change the answer, but as you've described it, it certainly sounds like a First Amendment violation. I practice in this area in your state, so I don't want to comment on it publicly beyond saying that you should look for an Ohio lawyer who does First Amendment law.

Do you have the text of the policy? I think you must be misunderstanding the scope of the rule.

If it's only related to use of the school's computer, they almost certainly have the right. They can also have policies about what you do while at school (many schools have been implementing policies regarding non-emergency use of cellphones).

@Barmar You are not going to be able to teach kids anything if they are allowed the distraction of a cellphone.

@NeilMeyer That's what I said, many schools prohibit use of phones during class.
